# How to pass a class in interface definition

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dependency-injection, interface

I create `BaseService` with common functions for all entities which inherit the base object, `public class Committee : BaseObject`:

```
public interface IBaseService<T> where T : BaseObject
{
}

public class BaseService<T> : IBaseService<T> where T : BaseObject
{
}
```

injection:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseService<>), typeof(BaseService<>));
```

then I use it like this:

```
readonly IBaseService<Committee> _committeeService;
```

But for some entities, which also inherits the base object `public class Evaluation : BaseObject`, I need a service, for each, with some extra business logic. So, I create a specific service which inherits base service:

```
public interface IEvaluationService<T> : IBaseService<T> where T : Evaluation
{
}

public class EvaluationService<T> : BaseService<Evaluation>, IEvaluationService<Evaluation>
{
}
```

injection:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IEvaluationService<>), typeof(EvaluationService<>));
```

and usage is like this:

```
readonly IEvaluationService<Evaluation> _evaluationService;
```

This code works just fine. But I'm wondering, why I have to pass `<Evaluation>` when I use `IEvaluationService<Evaluation>`. Why cannot I use it just like this:

```
readonly IEvaluationService _evaluationService;
```

???

The entity `Evaluation` is already passed in the `IEvaluationService` definition.
Why do I need to pass it again in usage?

Is there a way to simplify the usage of this service to be just `readonly IEvaluationService _evaluationService;`?

Comment: Using a service factory pattern may be in your best interest, as that would alleviate the necessity to inherit all of the base classes, and your code style issue.

Comment: What do you expect compiler to do with `readonly IEvaluationService _evaluationService;` as it would not know types of methods or properties/fields of that object that use generic argument (like `T GetMyData(){...}`) ? It is quite possible that you have useful usage hidden in the question but as written now that request does not come out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is declared with a type parameter `T`:

```
public interface IEvaluationService<T> : IBaseService<T> where T : Evaluation
{
}
```

That type parameter is *not* optional. While the `T` is constrained to `Evaluation`, this only means that `T` may be `Evaluation` *or any subtype* of `Evaluation`.

While `IEvaluationService<Evaluation>` is certainly valid, so would `IEvaluationService<SubEvaluation>` be, if `SubEvaluation : Evaluation`.

Thus, when you've declared the interface like that, you have to state which `T` you're interested in.

If you only ever want to support `Evaluation`, and no subtypes of it, you could have declared the interface like this:

```
public interface IEvaluationService : IBaseService<Evaluation>
{
    // More members here..?
}
```

That would enable you to use it as `IEvaluationService`, because that type has no open generics.